# no usb boot after installed ubuntu 12.04

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, ubuntu-netbook

I installed ubuntu 12.04 server on a Samsung net book "NP-N100S-E02 from a usb stick the first time I booted this netbook after purchased it, now I can't find usb boot options in the Bios setup. Always the boot devices priority has no more than the STA Toshiba harddisk. Somebody mentioned that Grub could put itself on the USB MBR, that's why maybe USB BOOT doesn't exist anymore.  I'm asking if anybody confirm what I've been told or provide me with some advices on how to fix that, I'm really feeling lost

Comment: To be clear, you can't find the option to boot from USB in the BIOS when the USB is plugged in and you press the relevant F key to get to BIOS. This is not an Ubuntu problem. This is either a problem with the BIOS or with the USB.

Comment: This question is about installing/trying Ubuntu. I think it is perfectly legitimate, I see no reason to close it.

Answer (score 1):

Technically grub can do that, but I find that rather unlikely. I suspect this is misconfigured BIOS.

Enable USB support in BIOS and twiddle with the boot order. Many BIOS also have a key to display a menu of available boot devices for you to select during boot.

Comment: Actually F4 displays the boot options but only the hard-disk shows when this is pressed,  is there no way to remove GRUB from the USB master-boot record?

Comment: Usually the BIOS doesn't care, if there's a boot loader on a device. It will just skip it and print an error when there is no selected bootable device at all. Is USB support enables in BIOS?

Comment: There's nothing about USB enabling/disabling from the Bios, the only related USB config. In the Bios Aptio setup utility is "USB S3 wake-up"